# How do I use CSS to alter the colour of my logo when I scroll onto a different background colour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I currently have a white SVG logo that I am using as my website is mostly dark backgrounds. However, I do have a section that is white so I am looking to change the colour of the logo to black while scrolling through the white section.

Here is a copy of the logo code and white section:

```
<!-- Logo -->
<div class="logo" style="display: block;">
  <a href="#home"></a> 
</div>

<!-- About -->
<div class="scrollview about">
  <div class="col-sm-3">

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my current styles:

```
.logo {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin: 20px;
   padding: 2.8em 2.8em;
   z-index: 9;
}
.logo a {
   width: 95px;
   height: 16px;
   display: block !important;
   background-image: url('../img/logo-light.png') transparent 0 0 no-repeat;
   background-image: none,url('../img/logo-light.svg');
}
.about {
  padding: 12.25em 10.25em;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

I'm not sure if it can be done using only CSS, but if someone can even point me towards a plugin or script it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: can send fiddle here?

Comment: Yeah I know what your saying. Thanks. Here is an example. Like I said though I'm not sure how this guy done it. www.plasticbcn.com/en/works/fullstackfest

Comment: Use two logos and switch between them

Answer (score 3):

You can't use CSS like that to change the style of an SVG that's in a separate file.  CSS rules do not cross document boundaries.

To style the SVG, you would need to need to inline it in your HTML page.

Assuming you made that change, then you could add a scroll event handler to the page and watch the position of the logo.  If you detect it is at the right point on the page (ie. it is over the white section), then you could add a class to it (or the `<a>` or the `<div>`). The class would change the colour of the logo using `fill: black`, or whatever.

Have you considered an easier solution? Such as giving the logo a dark outline, so that it stands out when over the white background?

Answer (score 0):

The `fill` property in `CSS` is for filling in the color of a `SVGs`.

```
svg {
    fill: currentColor;
 }
```

But you can't change the color of your logo for specific section of your site.

Comment: I have seen it done but I'm not sure how it was done. post a link once I find one again. Found one. http://www.plasticbcn.com/en/works/fullstackfest/

Comment: ok i understand your problem and i add new Answer for you question with demo.

Answer (score 0):

i check your demo link and I found out that they are use `jquery` to add and remove css class from there logo.
So you need add `jquery` 2.3.+
get the value of the bottom of the `#main` element by adding the `offset` of that element plus its height, set it as a `variable`

```
var mainbottom = $('#main').offset().top + $('#main').height();
```

Now on scroll add `function`

```
$(window).on('scroll',function()
```

and in it just add

```
stop = Math.round($(window).scrollTop());
    if (stop > mainbottom) {
        $('.logo').addClass('logo-dark');
    } else {
        $('.logo').removeClass('logo-dark');
   }
```

Here's [demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/mrsahar/pen/eWxmOZ) I made for you hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example your are looking for
https://codepen.io/whatthephuc/pen/QQagBj

```js
// Detect request animation frame
var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame
  || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.msRequestAnimationFrame
  || window.oRequestAnimationFrame
  // IE Fallback, you can even fallback to onscroll
  || function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60) };
var lastPosition = -1;

// my Variables
var lastSection = false;
var replaceItemTop = -1;
var replaceItemBottom = -1;
var replaceItemHeight = -1;
 
// The Scroll Function
function loop(){
  var top = window.pageYOffset;
  // my variables

  // my sections to calculate stuff
  var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
  var replaceContainer = document.querySelectorAll('.js-replace');
  var replaceItem = document.querySelectorAll('.js-replace__item');

  if (replaceItem.length > 0) {
    // get top position of item from container, because image might not have loaded
    replaceItemTop = parseInt(replaceContainer[0].getBoundingClientRect().top);
    replaceItemHeight = replaceItem[0].offsetHeight;
    replaceItemBottom = replaceItemTop + replaceItemHeight;
  }

  var sectionTop = -1;
  var sectionBottom = -1;
  var currentSection = -1;
  
  // Fire when needed
  if (lastPosition == window.pageYOffset) {
    scroll(loop);
    return false;
  } else {
    lastPosition = window.pageYOffset;

  // Your Function
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(sections, function(el, i){
    sectionTop = parseInt(el.getBoundingClientRect().top);
    sectionBottom = parseInt(el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom);

    // active section
    if ( (sectionTop <= replaceItemBottom) && (sectionBottom > replaceItemTop)) {
      // check if current section has bg
      currentSection = el.classList.contains('section--bg');

      // switch class depending on background image
      if ( currentSection ) { 
        replaceContainer[0].classList.remove('js-replace--reverse');
      } else {
        replaceContainer[0].classList.add('js-replace--reverse')
      }
    }
    // end active section

    // if active Section hits replace area
    if ( (replaceItemTop < sectionTop) && ( sectionTop <= replaceItemBottom) ) {
      // animate only, if section background changed
      if (currentSection != lastSection)  {
        document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--replace-offset', 100 / replaceItemHeight * parseInt(sectionTop - replaceItemTop) + '%');
      }
    }
    // end active section in replace area

    // if section above replace area
    if ( replaceItemTop >= sectionTop ) {
      // set offset to 0 if you scroll too fast
      document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--replace-offset', 0 + '%');
      // set last section to current section
      lastSection = currentSection;
    }

  }); 

}

// Recall the loop
scroll( loop )
}

// Call the loop for the first time
loop();

window.onresize = function(event) {
  loop();
};
```

```css
/* variables */
:root {
  --black: #000;
  --white: #fff;
  --color-1: #000;
  --gutter: 2rem;
  /* this value is going to be changed by javascript */
  --replace-offset: 50%;
  --replace-offset-2: calc((100% - var(--replace-offset) ) * -1)
}

/* set image position */
img {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

/* Sticky Footer */
.body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
  padding: calc(var(--gutter) * .5);
  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
}

/* without fixed header this makes no sense */
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: calc(var(--gutter) * .5);
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid;
  padding: calc(var(--gutter) * .25);
  border-radius: calc(var(--gutter) * .25);
  font-size: 2em;
}

.logo--invert {
  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
  border-color: var(--white);
}

.section {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding-top: var(--gutter);
  padding-bottom: var(--gutter);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.section--bg {
  background-color: var(--color-1);
}

/**
  This is the interesting part
**/

/* align content above each other without absolute */
.js-replace {
  display: grid;
}

.js-replace__item {
  grid-row: -1 / 1;
  grid-column: -1 / 1; 
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
}

/* item to replace with */
.js-replace__item {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset) * 1));  
}
.js-replace__content {
  /* fixes problem with calculating correct height in js */
  border: 1px solid transparent; 
  will-change: transform;

  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset) * -1));
}

/* previous replace item*/
.js-replace__item--active {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset-2) * 1));  
}
.js-replace__item--active .js-replace__content {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset-2) * -1));  
}


/* REVERSE ANIMATION */
.js-replace--reverse 
.js-replace__item {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset-2) * 1));  
}
.js-replace--reverse 
.js-replace__content {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset-2) * -1));
}

/* previous replace item*/
.js-replace--reverse 
.js-replace__item--active {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset) * 1));  
}
.js-replace--reverse 
.js-replace__item--active .js-replace__content {
  transform: translateY(calc(var(--replace-offset) * -1));
}
```

```html
<body class="body">
  <header class="header"> 
    <!-- replace content -->
    <div class="header__logo  js-replace">
      <!-- item to replace -->
      <div class="js-replace__item  js-replace__item--active">
        <div class="js-replace__content">
          <div class="logo">Logo</div>
        </div>
      </div>  
      <!-- end item to replace -->
     
      <!-- item to replace with -->
      <div class="js-replace__item">
        <div class="js-replace__content">
          <div class="logo  logo--invert">Logo</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end item to replace with -->
    </div>
    <!-- end replace content -->
  </header>

  <main class="main">
    <section class="section--1  section">
      <h1 class="section__title">

      </h1>
    </section>
    
    <section class="section--2  section  section--bg">
      <h1 class="section__title">

      </h1>      
    </section>
    
    <section class="section--3  section">
      <h1 class="section__title">

      </h1>
    </section>
    
    <section class="section--4  section  section--bg">
      <h1 class="section__title">

      </h1>      
    </section>
    
    <section class="section--5  section">
      <h1 class="section__title">

      </h1>
    </section> 
  </main>

  <footer class="footer">
    &copy; Phuc Le - Webdeveloper
  </footer>
</body>
```